# Should I space out question asking to prevent quickly pushing questions asked by other users off the front page?

Tags: discussion

If I have many questions I deem suitable for asking on this site, is it best to space out the question-asking over a certain amount of time to prevent quickly pushing questions asked by other users off the front page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should be asking **questions you encounter in your day-to-day activities**, so it's a bit unusual to encounter a pile of eclectic questions to ask all at once. If you are asking questions simply to start filling this site, please at least read

[**Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

If a user starts rapid-firing off questions, it starts to look a bit like someone is coming up with questions just for the sake of asking questions. The very real concern is, if people feel that the author doesn’t really care about the answers, the whole exercise would likely be perceived as a waste of time.

One of the major motivations of using this site is to help people. You don't want your front page to look like a quiz show with busy work. There are very real people on this site taking time out of their day to share their hard-earned knowledge, thinking they are helping folks with genuine problems.

I don't know where you got all these questions, but think about what you are asking and make sure you are asking out of genuine need; pace yourself. There's nothing inherently wrong with having multiple questions if the situation arises. But there's no need to load up this site with idle questions just to up the numbers. It can become counter productive very quickly.